# PHP: Merge 3 Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to merge 3 dimentional array with php and need result. Tell me how to achieve this. Below is my two array output. Is there any inbuilt function available for this ?

### Array1

```
Array
(
    [4af2986d-92d6-f343-4c55-5da954718c48] => Array
        (
            [2020-01-10] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [Call_Answered] => 0
                            [Call_Dropes] => 1
                            [call_duration_seconds] => 0
                        )                    

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [Call_Answered] => 2
                            [Call_Dropes] => 1
                            [call_duration_seconds] => 91
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

### Array2

```
Array
(
    [4af2986d-92d6-f343-4c55-5da954718c48] => Array
        (
            [2020-01-10] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [break_duration] => 19
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [break_duration] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

### Result_array

```
Array
(
    [4af2986d-92d6-f343-4c55-5da954718c48] => Array
        (
            [2020-01-10] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [Call_Answered] => 0
                            [Call_Dropes] => 1
                            [call_duration_seconds] => 0
                            [break_duration] => 19
                        )                    

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [Call_Answered] => 2
                            [Call_Dropes] => 1
                            [call_duration_seconds] => 91
                        )
                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [user_name] => dreamertechs
                            [break_duration] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have used beow function but not get the aspected result.

```
$array = array_unique (array_merge ($call_data, $break_data));
```

Comment: In the future, please 1. exhaustively research (because nearly every basic data manipulation is already provided in the millions of pages created over the last 10 years 2. Show you array data as `var_export()` or a json_encoded string instead of `print_r()` or `var_dump()` -- this allows volunteers to instantly use your exact data in their answers.

Answer (score -1):

[array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) will do here:

```
<?php

$one =
[
    'a1' =>  [
        '2010' => [
            1 => [
                'name' => 'Ringo'
            ],
            2 => [
                'name' => 'Paul'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$two =
[
    'a1' =>  [
        '2010' => [
            1 => [
                'name' => 'Ringo',
                'instrument' => 'Drums'
            ],
            3 => [
                'name' => 'George'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

var_export(array_replace_recursive($two, $one));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a1' => 
  array (
    2010 => 
    array (
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Ringo',
        'instrument' => 'Drums',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'George',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Paul',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```